# Google oauth2 Java Contacts Service - Conflict in documentation

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, gdata, gdata-api

I have registered my web application for use with oath2 using the following instructions:

http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2.html

This means my client is created with a client ID, client secret and Redirect URI.

Once I have configured my web application as per

http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer.html

I recieve a code in a request parameter from google, which I can then use to request an access token, which comes in a JSON in a format along the lines of:

{
  "access_token":"1/fFAGRNJru1FTz70BzhT3Zg",
  "expires_in":3920,
  "token_type":"Bearer"
}

Once this is done, I can use that access token to access a google api on behalf of the user:

GET https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=1/fFBGRNJru1FQd44AzqT3Zg

This as documented is done by simply passing the access token as a request parameter.

However when I move onto using a Java API (In this case google contacts) I get the following in the documentation for HMAC-SHA1:

```
GoogleOAuthParameters oauthParameters = new GoogleOAuthParameters();
oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY);
oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET);
oauthParameters.setOAuthToken(ACCESS_TOKEN);
oauthParameters.setOAuthTokenSecret(TOKEN_SECRET);

DocsService client = new DocsService("yourCompany-YourAppName-v1");
client.setOAuthCredentials(oauthParameters, new OAuthHmacSha1Signer());

URL feedUrl = new URL("https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full");
DocumentListFeed resultFeed = client.getFeed(feedUrl, DocumentListFeed.class);
for (DocumentListEntry entry : resultFeed.getEntries()) {
  System.out.println(entry.getTitle().getPlainText());
}
```

Or the following for RSA-SHA1

```
GoogleOAuthParameters oauthParameters = new GoogleOAuthParameters();
oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY);
oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET);
oauthParameters.setOAuthToken(ACCESS_TOKEN);

PrivateKey privKey = getPrivateKey("/path/to/your/rsakey.pk8");  // See above for the defintion of getPrivateKey()

DocsService client = new DocsService("yourCompany-YourAppName-v1");
client.setOAuthCredentials(oauthParameters, new OAuthRsaSha1Signer(privKey));

URL feedUrl = new URL("https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full");
DocumentListFeed resultFeed = client.getFeed(feedUrl, DocumentListFeed.class);
for (DocumentListEntry entry : resultFeed.getEntries()) {
  System.out.println(entry.getTitle().getPlainText());
}
```

First off, it seems that if I was doing standard http rather than the java wrapper, all I would need to provide is an access token.  Am I missing something or where have these additional parameters come from?  Mainly TOKEN_SECRET, which there is no mention of in the docunentation.  There is also no mention of having to provide CONSUMER_KEY and CONSUMER_SECRET.  I am presuming they are alternative names for client id and client secret, but I do not understand why I am now having to provide them.  Finally when setting up my application using the google API's console, there was no mention whatsoever of the two different encryption types, and which one I am going to be using, am I missing something here aswell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java code examples you show are based on OAuth 1.0 (not OAuth 2.0) which has some crypto requirements which were simplified in OAuth 2.0.  In some cases with the Google Contacts API you need OAuth 1.0.  See: http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/3.0/developers_guide.html#GettingStarted

Comment: I am looking where you have directed me, there is a working example linked which does not use Oauth, then below it tells me to use Oauth 2.0 which gets to Step 6 "Your application requests user data, attaching the access token to the request." but does not give an example.  Then below that there are no examples of Oauth. On the Oauth 2.0 pages it directs me to, it only gives examples of using straight http and not any java apis.  Confusing again google.